# Why are my if-statements not executing in order?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, cs50

so there is this coding question (from CS50's introduction to programming with python week 2, loops) where user input is reviewed by your program to check if it satisfies a set of conditions. The problem is as follows in the screenshot [here is the full problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UMAI.png). Although not included in the conditions the input can be all text and the output should still be "valid".

so here is the program that i have written and implemented. For some reason, it seems to be picking up until the first if-statement, where it does return "Valid" when prompted with all-text input. However, once my input is no longer text only and now contains other types of input, the program stops functions, seemingly at all. I personally think the problem is with the order of if statements and their functionality relative to that, because the debug print-statements i have placed throughout the "else" statement is not executing at all.
Thank you for your time,

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def is_valid(s):
    if 2 <= len(s) <= 6 and s.isalpha():
        return True


    else:
        if s.isalnum():
            for letter in range(len(s)):
                print(s[letter])
                return letter
            if s[letter].isdigit():
                first_number , rest = s.split(s[letter])
                print(first_number , rest)
                if int(first_number) > 0 and rest.isdigit():
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
main()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show some example runs. This should include all input and output for each example.

Comment: If you have a `return` in your `if` the `else:` is unnecessary, it's implied. This helps reduce indentation if you can "flatten" code. You can also `return` a logical test like `return x < y` instead of `if x < y: return True` etc.

Comment: Why is there a `return` in your `for letter in range(len(s))` loop? That will exit the function after one character.

Comment: Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: There are several problems in your code: 1. No `else` with `if s.isalnum()`, so the function will return `None` rather than an explicit boolean. 2. A `return` in the `for` loop that ends the function early. Also, this returns a character rather than a boolean value, so it is inconsistent with the other return types. Note that you can find these kinds of mistakes on your own by using the techniques from the article I linked earlier.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal this seems to be the problem when I run my code, so how do I get input back from the loop?

Comment: @Xenesis2k That completely depends on what you want to get out of the loop. What are you trying to achieve with it? Get the indices of digits? Get the first non-alphabetic character? Or something else entirely?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank you much for all these tips, especially the article you attached, however, and as I have mentioned earlier to another person, how do I get back the value from the loop without the return function? again thank you for your time

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I'm just trying to return the indicia of the character in case it is a digit, so for example, if I were to write CS50 I want to return the index of "5" in my input

Comment: @Xenesis2k Create a variable, e.g. `index = -1`, to store your index above the loop. In your loop body, you can use `if s[letter].isdigit(): index = letter; break`. Then, you can leave out the `if s[letter].isdigit():` statement, since we already know the license plate is not fully alphabetic, so the for loop _must_ return the index of a number.

Comment: @Xenesis2k What "value from the loop" do you need to "get back"?

Comment: "I'm just trying to return the indicia of the character in case it is a digit" So your `is_valid()` function returns an integer index in one case, but returns a boolean in all other cases. This raises a red flag for me because you need to return a different type in one case. A function should be defined so that it always returns the same type. Also, this violates the Single Responsibility Principle because your function is trying to do two different things at once. I recommend that you read about this principle and rethink your function design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution to the problem:

```py
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def is_valid(s):
    if 2 <= len(s) <= 6:
        numsStarted = False;
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if (i < 2):
                if (not s[i].isalpha()):
                    return False
            elif (numsStarted and not (s[i] >= '0' and s[i] <= '9')):
                return False
            elif (s[i] >= '0' and s[i] <= '9'):
                numsStarted = True;
            elif (s[i].isalpha()):
                continue
            else:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False
main()
```

In this code, I start the same way you did with checking that `s` is the correct length, then I have a for loop to take me through all the characters in `s`. In this loop, I check first whether the character is a number, if it is I check that all remaining characters are a number, if not, then I return `False`. If it's not a number, I check to see if it's a letter, and finally, if it's anything else, I just return `False`. If my code manages to reach the end of the loop, I can safely assume every character in `s` was a letter, and return `True`

You had a couple of little problems in your code which caused it to not work properly. Firstly, you have a return statement in one of your if statements which caused the function to return a value prematurely. You also are missing an else statement for the `if s.isalnum():` which meant that the function would sometimes return a `None` value.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for letter in range(len(s)):
                print(s[letter])
                return letter
```

The return statement exits the function and returns the variable "letter" as the value of "plate". This is why the rest of your if-statements are not executing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems, first there is no need of the `print` calls inside the loop, get rid of them.

Second `return` in your code breaks the loop prematurely, it is wrong, remove it.

Third don't do `for i in range(len(s)): s[i]`, just do `for i in s: i`.

Fourth your if condition needs to be inside the for loop, not under it.

Fixed code:

```py
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def is_valid(s):
    if 2 <= len(s) <= 6 and s.isalpha():
        return True


    if s.isalnum():
        for char in s:
            if char.isdigit():
                first_number , rest = s.split(char)
                if int(first_number) > 0 and rest.isdigit():
                    return True

main()
```

But your solution isn't efficient. I don't know what inputs are valid. A wild guess: an alphanumeric string that ends with all digits and the second digit is greater than zero, we can use a simple regex to solve it:

```
import re

def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if re.match('^([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z]*\d[1-9]\d*)$', plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
```

We can make the code more concise:

```
def main(plate):
    print('In'*(not re.match('^([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z]*\d[1-9]\d*)$', plate)) + 'Valid')
```